# convert string with multiple dict appearance

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Explaination

I'm using *psycopg2* to store my results and to recover them. I'm storing a list like this in my table :

```
[{"vlan": "715", "intf": "0/3", "intf2": "0/4"}, {"vlan": "", "intf": "0/5", "intf2": "0/6"}, {"vlan": "", "intf": "0/7", "intf2": ""}]
```

When I do a SELECT on this table, here is the output :

```
[('[{"vlan": "715", "intf": "0/3", "intf2": "0/4"}, {"vlan": "", "intf": "0/5", "intf2": "0/6"}, {"vlan": "", "intf": "0/7", "intf2": ""}]',)]
```

To print the string, I do :

```
test = [('[{"vlan": "715", "intf": "0/3", "intf2": "0/4"}, {"vlan": "", "intf": "0/5", "intf2": "0/6"}, {"vlan": "", "intf": "0/7", "intf2": ""}]',)]

print(type(test))
test = test[0][0]
print(type(test))

out:
<class 'list'>
<class 'str'>
```

## What I've tried

I've tried with modules **json** and **ast** but I didn't succeed due to the multiple dict I think.

## What I would like to do

I would like to browse through the dict (which is currently a string) and have a result like this :

```
for om in test
    print(om["intf"])

out:
0/3
0/5
0/7
```

Or something like this.

Hope you understood what I want to do.

Comment: store the value as json type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a list of dicts embedded in a JSON string.

Use this code to extract your data:

```
import json

test = [('[{"vlan": "715", "intf": "0/3", "intf2": "0/4"}, {"vlan": "", "intf": "0/5", "intf2": "0/6"}, {"vlan": "", "intf": "0/7", "intf2": ""}]',)]
j = json.loads(test[0][0]) #list of dicts

for d in j:
    print(d['intf'])
```

output:

```
0/3
0/5
0/7
```

Answer (score 2):

`json.loads` would be better:

```
import json
lot = json.loads(lot[0][0])
for i in lot:
    print(i['intf'])
```

Output:

```
0/3
0/5
0/7
>>>
```

Comment: your answer and @alec_djinn answer same approach, you should try a different one,  try with `ast` module